# SweaveListingUtils and line numbers

Tags: r, sweave, latex

I'm currently trying to use [SweaveListingUtils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SweaveListingUtils/index.html). Because of the vignette, the first steps are quite easy.

Only the line numbers (including references) are not working as intended/expected (the relevant Sweave/R/LaTeX code is posted below):

```
<<exam001>>=
x <- rnorm(3) # comment (*\label{comment1}*)
print(round(x, 2))
a <- 2 # comment (*\label{comment2}*)
@
Note that line \ref{comment1} and \ref{comment2} contain comments.
```

The output should contain the executed code and the printing including **line numbers from 1 to 3**. *But the numeration restarts after the print command!*

Also the references are affected:

```
Note that line 1 and 1 contain comment.
```

Does anyone know how to get correct line numbering using Sweave and SweaveListingUtils? (I assume that the solution works with printing, plotting etc. from/in the R code!)